# Android, the dates are not saved in DB

Tags: java, android, date, save

I can not understand what the problem, have a look at my code.

Constructor of Note, accepts an object type Date:

```
public Nota(String titolo, String testo, Date data, int colore) {
    this.titolo = titolo;
    this.testo = testo;
    this.data = data;
    // controlla che l'id del radiobutton non sia -1
    if( colore == -1 ){
        Log.w("Color", "Errore id Colore del Radio Button");
    }else{
        this.colore = colore;
    }
}
```

The Date is passed here, when occurs saving the Note in the DB:

```
private void insertInDB() {
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ITALY);
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ITALY);
    Date date = now.getTime();
    String dteStr = rifDate.getText().toString();
    // provo a parsare una String in Date
    try{
        date = format.parse(rifDate.getText().toString());
        // cattura l'eccezione
    }catch (ParseException pe){
        pe.printStackTrace();
    }
    nota = new Nota(rifTitleNote.getText().toString(),    rifWriteEdit.getText().toString(), date,    idRadioGroup);
    now.setTime(date);
    // if the insertion is successful ok, otherwise return -1
    boolean insNoteCheck = dbNote.insertNote(nota);
}
```

Here, is the method of insert in the class Database which extends SQLiteOnHelper:

```
public boolean insertNote(Nota nota){
    // boolean inizializzat a false utilizzata come return
    boolean resultInsert = false;
    // repository dei dati in modalità scrittura
    SQLiteDatabase dbLite = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // utilizza un ContentValues come mappa di valori, dove le columns rappresentano le chiavi
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("titoloNota", nota.getTitolo());
    values.put("testoNota", nota.getTesto());
    values.put("dataNota", nota.getData()); // getData() return a String
    values.put("coloreNota", nota.getColore());
```

Method getData() which return a String:

```
public String getData() {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy", Locale.ITALY);
    return DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(data); // data is Data type passed to the Constructor
}
```

Then, I have an Inner static class for the DatePickerDialog, where I set the EditText of date, here the method **onDateSet()**:

```
public void onDateSet(android.widget.DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        EditText date = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editData);
        //System.out.println("QUESTA DATAA   :"+ anno + " " + mese + " " + giorno);
        // setto il testo della Data aggiungendo +1 al mese poichè in Calendar sono rappresentati(0-11)
        date.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
    }
```

and finally I have an Adapter for the list of element, in the method **onBindViewHolder()** that there is this line to display the date in the list

```
holder.txtDate.setText("Data: " + arrayList.get(position).getDataa());
```

I have done several times to understand what the problem, but unfortunately no way.
Through the System.out.println() when creating the Note in the Logcat I see the date correctly.
But I have the impression that the **date will not be saved in DB**, in fact in the list (Adapter), the dates are all initialized 1/gen/1970.

Answer (score 1):

As per this link [Datatypes in SQLLite](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
>   and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
>   are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
>   values:

So one way to store dates is to use INTEGER as the column type. Then use date.getTime() to get the epoch time, i.e. epoch time as a long type in milliseconds, as the value to store.

When reading from the database, use date.setTime(long) to set the date variable.

Comment: I solved changing in Integer and values.put("dataNota", nota.getDataa().getTime()).
Could you explain why it is necessary call getTime()?!
Thanks

Comment: Because getTime() returns a long, which can be stored in a column defined as INTEGER in Sqllite.